# How to get a pointer for an inode of a file

Tags: directory, inode

In order to add some security measure for Linux kernel I am trying to add extra flags in the inode structure.

A system call would check this flag if its set for a certain file.

So how can I access the inode structure (through a pointer probably) of a file knowing its directory &/or its inode number?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just need SELinux, or maybe even ACLs?

Comment: Yes you should really be looking at SELinux if you're attempting to add security for process & file system interactions. That project has extensive capabilities and it's been hardened for several years!

Answer (score 2):

SELinux provides hooks to add checks based on inode access. Check out this link titled: [Inode Hook Functions](http://www.nsa.gov/research/_files/selinux/papers/module/x970.shtml).

*excerpt*

> The SELinux inode hook function implementations manage the security
>   fields of inode structures and perform access control for inode
>   operations. Since inodes are used to represent pipes, files, and
>   sockets, the hook functions must handle each of these abstractions.
>   Furthermore, these hooks must handle multiple filesystem types,
>   including both conventional disk-based filesystems like ext3 and
>   pseudo filesystems like proc and tmpfs. This section begins by
>   describing the inode hook functions for managing the security fields.
>   It then discusses the inode hook functions for performing access
>   control.

Here's a [good tutorial on getting started with SELinux](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/getting_started_with_SELinux/).

#### References

- [Implementing SELinux as a Linux Security Module](http://www.nsa.gov/research/_files/selinux/papers/module/t1.shtml)
- [Implementing SELinux as a Linux Security Module - Inode Hook Functions](http://www.nsa.gov/research/_files/selinux/papers/module/x970.shtml)
- [linuxtopia SELinux tutorial](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/getting_started_with_SELinux/)